# Why does vi show the ends of lines as $?

Tags: ascii, vi

I am using vi on Mac, and when I've run `:set list`, a `$` (dollar sign) character is displayed at the end of each line. My confusion is that `$` is not the ASCII value for a newline. Why does `$` represent the end of the line?

Answer (score 2):

`$` was chosen as the default value to display to represent the line, probably because `$` is the command to move the cursor to the end of the line, which was probably chosen because `$` represents an end of line anchor in a regular expression.  There's nothing magical about it, and you can use any character you want by setting `listchars`.  `:help listchars` for details.

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there any web document I can refer to easily to have a table of such reserved characters (e.g. '$' in my sample) and its related meanings? I find the :help listchars are long document not very easy to read. :)

Comment: `:help 'list'` mentions that tab characters are displayed as CTRL-I (^I) and $ at the end of the line, plus whatever additional settings are specified by `listchars`. (You need the single quotes to indicate it is an option, otherwise it pulls up the help for the `:list` command.) Thus the default "reserved characters" are just `$` and `^I`.

If you change `listchars`, you can define additional special characters, but they won't appear by default. Note that `listchars` is a Vim extension and is not available in plain vi.